# How To Create Anchors within an image gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, anchor

**Hi Guys,**

I have a HTML/js code for a image gallery on my page, "gallery.html".
The scenario is that I have an external HTML page with different links. When I click on one of those link I want to redirect to this image gallery but to a specific image.

For e.g I have a page called "home.html" with a link called "img2". When I click on "img2" I want to open up this image gallery(which sits on a page called "gallery.html"), but I want tab 2 of the gallery to be opened so 2nd image.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="gallery" align="center">
<div class="thumbnails">
<img name="ift" onclick="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="IFT.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
<img onclick="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="Clear.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
<img onclick="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="Agile.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
<img onclick="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="AllForOne.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
<img onclick="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="Decide.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
<img onclick="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="Possibilities.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
</div><br/>

<div class="preview" align="center">
<img id="preview" src="IFT.png" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
</div>
```

**Thank you for your help in advance, Much appreciated.**

Comment: Where do you declare your vars: preview, img1, img2, etc.? Did you first try to do `onclick="document.getElementById('preview').src=document.getElementById('img6').src"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the name or the ID of the image to show to the URL (for example `gallery.html?img=img1`).

You can then use JavaScript in your image gallery code to read this parameter and switch to the image with this name/id.

Comment: Thank you very much firstly for fast response but most importantly it works :)